# Broadcasting in node-weighted graphs

Tags: graph-algorithms

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ with non-negative node-weights $\text{w}(v)$, $v \in V$, 
I want to find a spanning tree $T$ of $G$ with minimum "cost" 
$\text{w}(T) = \sum_{v\in V} \deg_T(v)\cdot \text{w}(v)$, where $\deg_T(v)$ is the degree of $v$ in $T$.

Can this spanning tree problem be solved efficiently?

Comment: I am afraid that this problem is too elementary for cstheory.stackexchange.com.  Spoiler: The problem can be formulated as a special case of the usual minimum spanning tree problem.

Comment: Indeed, this problem is a minimum spanning tree problem by defining
for each edge $e=uv$, $w'(e)=w(u)+w(v)$; the idea is similar to the answer
of the related question
http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/finding-a-minimum-node-weight-path

Comment: @Ito and user13136 This is a simple and yet elegant solution! Thank you very much!!!